# Come tradurre: Header image?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

Come posso tradurre **Header image** in italiano?

Il contesto è quello generale del web. Si intende l'immagine orizzontale che compare per esempio in alto nel profile facebook.

Un esempio di frase da tradurre è:

*The area reserved for header image is 1140px x 440px.*

Posso tradurre come **immagine d'intestazione**?

Non l'ho mai sentito prima :) ma dovrebbe essere corretto no?

Un'alternativa potrebbe essere **immagine header**. Meno corretto ma più comprensibile no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi sembra che vada benissimo “(immagine d')intestazione”.

Anche il Ragazzini (ma tu dai un'occhiata anche ai dizionari, vero?), per il significato informatico di *header*, dà «testata; intestazione; parte iniziale: “http header”, intestazione http».

(Riguardo alla comprensibilità, non sono sicuro che chi non ha a che fare con l'informatica o la tipografia anche in inglese sappia necessariamente cos'è uno *header*.)

Comment: Si un'occhiata ce l'ha do :) Però per l'uso comune chiedo il parere della comunità..

Comment: Mi sembra che siamo diventati un servizio di traduzione. Siamo sicuri che sia on-topic?

Comment: Grazie, @Gio, ma sono sicuro che johnnyfittizio sia sufficientemente sveglio da cogliere le mie allusioni al consultare i dizionari e al creare lui un suo glossario. :-)

Comment: Si, magari non dovremmo incoraggiare questo tipo di domande, ma capisco che siamo stimolanti per certi versi.

Comment: in ambito informatico si predilige una non traduzione, mantenendo http header. Di contro nell'esempio proposto è buono _immagine d'intestazione_ o _immagine di copertina_. Sebbene i due non siano equivalenti, bisogna anche capire il contesto e cosa un utente si aspetta di trovare

Answer (score 1):

Io ti suggerirei di usare l'espressione ***immagine di testa*** mutuata dal contesto giornalistico-editoriale:

> in t. alla pagina, al foglio, in t. all’avviso, in t. al cartellone,
>   ecc.; di qui, articolo di testa, titolo di testa, collocati in cima
>   alla pagina di un giornale, su una o più colonne (in cinematografia,
>   invece, si chiamano titoli di testa le didascalie che compaiono
>   all’inizio del film: v. titolo, n. 2 a).

Quindi tradurrei la tua frase come:

The area reserved for header image is 1140px x 440px.
*L'area riservata all'***immagine di testa*** è 1140px x 400px.*

Answer (score 0):

Se stai scrivendo un documento tecnico non tradurre proprio il termine (scrivi header image) oppure una forma ibrida come 'immagine di header'. 
Se invece stai scrivendo un documento per non addetti ai lavori 'immagine di testa' è corretto.

If you're writing to technicals use the English form untranslated or 'partially translated', if you're writing to general public 'immagine di testa' is acceptable.

== messaggio modificato ==

Comment: Potresti scrivere in modo più chiaro? Che cosa “è o di NON TRADURRE” etc.? Qual è il soggetto della frase?